# Model.find() returns null after model.save() in Mongoose + Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

The save function works perfectly but, the find function just below it returns null on searching the save object which is previously saved.
Here is the code:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var User = mongoose.model("User");

module.exports.register = function(req, res) {
  var user = new User();
  user.name = req.body.name;
  user.email = req.body.email;
  user.setPassword(req.body.password);
  user.save(function(err) {
    var token;
    token = user.generateJwt();
    res.status(200);
    res.json({
      token: token
    });
  });
  User.findById(user._id, function(err, particularDocument) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(particularDocument);
    }
  });
};
```

`User.findById()` return `null`. Even `User.find({})` returns `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both saving and finding data from the db is asynchronous in your code.

Since the results of the find depend on the save being finished, you must wait for the `save` to finish before calling `find` (or `findById`).

At the moment, you are executing them at the same time:

```
// call save but don't wait for it to finish
user.save(/* callback when save is done. this is executed sometime after all other code is done executing. */);
// call findById but don't wait for it to finish
User.findById(user._id, /* callback when find is done. this is executed sometime after all other code is done executing. */);
// continue here before any of the callbacks are executed
```

But you should execute them serially:

```
user.save(function() {
  User.findById(user._id, function(err, user) {
    // get user here
  })
  // ...
});
```

The reason this is necessary is because **asynchronous code runs some time after all the synchronous code is finished**.

In other words, no asynchronous code runs until the current segment of synchronous code is finished.